# Error e terminos de Python con PostgreSQL con Python (cmdlet)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Cordial saludo, necesito preguntarles por favor acerca de un error que me aparece  al momento de configurar Python con el framework Django en Visual Studio Code dentro de Windows 11

dentro del proceso de instalacion y configuración en la terminal o consola pongo lo siguiente:

```
PS C:\Users\hecamava\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql> virtualenv venv
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
virtualenv : El término 'virtualenv' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ virtualenv venv
```

Probando con ChatGPT me dice que es por problemas de configuración del PATH que no tengo registrado un paquete pero no sé cuál paquete o cómo configurar el PATH.

Igual me sucede cuando dentro de la terminal del visual studio code pongo: `django-admin startproject` me aparece de modo similar lo siguiente:

```
django-admin : El término 'django-admin' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.       
Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de       
nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ django-admin startproject
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de       
nuevo.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

¡Agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar!

Comment: Tengo una duda, estas intentando crear un entorno virtual o activarlo?

Comment: Estoy creando el entorno virtual con la siguiente línea dentro de la consola: PS C:\Users\hecamava\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql> virtualenv venv                         Pero ahi es en donde me empieza a salir el error.:   irtualenv : El término 'virtualenv' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Estas ejecutando un comando invalido al intentar crear el entorno. En tu caso necesitas algo así:

```
PS C:\Users\hecamava\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>python -m venv miEntorno
```

- El comando 'python' indica que ejecutaras una instancia de este.
- El comando 'venv' indica que crearas un entorno.
- Luego indicas la ruta donde quieres crear el entorno seguido del nombre de este. Si deseas crearlo en la ruta donde ya te encuentras posicionado puedes obviar la ruta y especificar directamente el nombre de tu entorno.

Ejemplo:

```
PS C:\Users\hecamava\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>python -m venv C:\Users\hecamava\Desktop\django-crud-postgresql>miEntorno
```

Si aun tienes dudas te dejo la documentación oficial de Python [Acá](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/venv.html).
Espero haberte sido de ayuda.